# Regex URL rewriting for custom login page

Tags: regex, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

I'm implementing a custom login page for a multitenant portal where each client gets a different login page styled according to their stored settings.
To achieve this I am using IIS 7.5 with the URL Rewriting module.
My idea is to capture requests for "http://portal.com/client1/" and rewrite them into "http://portal.com/login.aspx?client=client1".

What I'm struggling with is the regex expression to match the URL and extract the "client1" bit out.

EXAMPLES:
    "http://portal.com/pepsi" = "http://portal.com/login.aspx?client=pepsi"
    "http://portal.com/fedex" = "http://portal.com/login.aspx?client=fedex"
    "http://portal.com/northwind" = "http://portal.com/login.aspx?client=northwind"
    "http://portal.com/microsoft/" = "http://portal.com/login.aspx?client=microsoft"

So the match should be found if the requested URL contains a single word after the first "/" and work whether there is a trailing "/" or not.

```
"http://portal.com/clients/home.aspx" would be ignored by the rule.
"http://portal.com/clients/catalog" would be ignored by the rule.
"http://portal.com/products.aspx" would be ignored by the rule.
```

Comment: be good to have some examples. e.g. do you care about the trailing `/` ?  what if something comes after `clientX/`?  etc

Comment: Please see my examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

- That the parameter name is always `client`
- and that you don't care about what is after `/client1/` then you can use this simple pattern to capture that portion of the URL and then repeat it as a parameter

here:

```
<rewrite>  
  <rules>
     <rule name="client1 rewrite">
      <match url="^([^/.]*)[/]*$" />
      <action type="rewrite" url="login.aspx?client={R:1}"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

### [Fiddle](http://fiddle.re/17wk6)

This works because in all of the ignore list there is a slash in the "middle", but the slash is optional at ending of the "filter" list.  So `{R:1}` will contain everything up to the first slash or end of url if there is no slash.

Comment: Thanks gillyspy:)
Your assumptions are correct but the "client1" bit is not constant.
I will amend my question to be more precise.

Comment: sorry...tired.  okay fixed it so that `client1` portion can be anything but the parameter is still called `client`

Comment: Sorry it took me few attempts to express the real issue:)

Comment: Your current solution seems to be matching any URL.
Also, is it possible to not match when there is a "." anywhere in the URL. As in my latest example. I'm beginning to suspect I would be better off just writing my own module to intercept/massage requests in the processing pipeline:)

Comment: ok updated it for you.  please see fiddle for MSDN test as I didn't test this change directly with IIS

Comment: Thanks - gillyspy:) Awesome job!